# return and return None in a generator: PEP guidelines

Tags: python, generator, yield, pep

According to PEP 8 we should be consistent in our function declarations and ensure that they all have the same return-pattern, i.e. all should return an expression or all should not. However, I am not sure how to apply this to generators.

A generator will `yield` values as long as the code reaches them, unless a `return` statement is encountered in which case it will stop the iteration. However, I don't see any use-case in which returning a value from a generator function can happen. In that spirit, I don't see why it is useful - from a PEP 8 perspective - to end such a function with the explicit `return None`. In other words, why do we ought to verbalize a return statement for generators if the return expression is only reached when the yield'ing is over?

Example: in the following code, I don't see how `hello()` can be used to assign `100` to a variable (thus using the return statement). So why does PEP 8 expect us to write a return statement (be it `100` or `None`).

```
def hello():
    for i in range(5):
      yield i

    return 100


h = [x for x in hello()]
g = hello()

print(h)    
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(g)
# <generator object hello at 0x7fd2f285a7d8>
# can we ever get 100?
```

Comment: You have misread PEP 8. The consistency is **within a single function**, not across all your functions.

Comment: If you do occasionally return a value or None from the same function, write that as `return None`, not just a plain `return`. And for generators, apply the same lesson: `yield None` versus `yield`, if elsewhere you do yield some value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misread PEP8. PEP8 states:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either **all return statements in a function** should return an expression, or none of them should.

(bold emphasis mine)

You should be consistent with how you use `return` within a single function, not across your whole project.

Use `return`, it's the only `return` statement in the function.

> However, I don't see any use-case in which returning a value from a generator function can happen.

The return value of a generator is attached to the `StopIteration` exception raised:

```
>>> def gen():
...     if False: yield
...     return 'Return value'
...
>>> try:
...     next(gen())
... except StopIteration as ex:
...     print(ex.value)
...
Return value
```

And this is also the mechanism by which `yield from` produces a value; the return value of `yield from` is the `value` attribute on the `StopIteration` exception. A generator can thus return a result to code using `result = yield from generator` by using `return result`:

```
>>> def bar():
...     result = yield from gen()
...     print('gen() returned', result)
...
>>> next(bar(), None)
gen() returned Return value
```

This feature is used in the Python standard library; e.g. in the `asyncio` library the value of `StopIteration` is used to pass along `Task` results, and the `@coroutine` decorator uses `res = yield from ...` to run a wrapped generator or awaitable and pass through the return value.

So, from a PEP-8  point of view, for generators and there are two possibilities:

- You are using `return` to exit the generator early, say in a loop with `if`. Use `return`, no need to add `None`:

  ```
  def foo():
      while bar:
          yield ham
          if spam:
              return
  ```
- You are using `return <something>` to exit *and* set `StopIteration.value`. Use `return <something>` consistently throughout your generator, *even when returning `None`*:

  ```
  def foo():
      for bar in baz:
          yield bar
          if spam:
              return 'The bar bazzed the spam'
      return None
  ```

Comment: Ah yes, I see. My bad about the interpretation. So in general, one doesn't use the return value in a generator - but to comply with PEP 8 we should still return None, correct?

Comment: @BramVanroy: you *do* use `return` in a generator, either to just exit the generator at that point, or to exit and set the `StopIteration.value` value. When you use `return` for the first case, just use `return`. There is no need to add `None`. PEP-8 only says that if you use more than one `return` statement in a (generator) function, then they all should use the same pattern.

Comment: @BramVanroy: so if your generator uses `return value` in one place, and `return` in another, then you'd use `return None` in that other place.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning `yield from`. Catching `StopIteration` manually and examining the exception's attached `value` is an unusual way to use a generator's return value, in much the same way catching `StopIteration` manually is an unusual thing to do in general.